# Question related to Erdös-Szekeres Happy Ending problem

Tags: geometry, ramsey-theory

After reading the papers of Erdös and Szekeres regarding the "*Happy Ending problem*", I am wondering if there is some research / paper regarding the existence of a given number of points $F_2(n)$ in general position such that *every* subset of $n$ points is a convex n-gon.

For instance, $F_2(3)=3$, as every set of three points forms a triangle, which is always convex. I am not sure if $F_2(n>3)$ does even exist, I have not found an example of such a set of points. I guess that it does not exist, but I am not sure of how it would be possible to prove it.

If we generalize the question to three dimensions, regarding the existence of a given number of points $F_3(n)$ in general position such that *every* subset of $n$ points is a convex polyhedron, I get that $F_3(4)=4$, because every set of four points in general position in three dimensions form a convex polyhedron.

Thus, it can be conjectured that, for a given $d$ number of dimensions, the only given number of points $F_d(n)$ such that *every* subset of $n$ points is a given convex polytope is $F_d(n=d+1)=d+1$. Also, it seems trivial that necessarily $F_d(n<d+1)$ does not exist, as it is impossible to form any convex $d$-polytope with $d$ or less points.

If you could provide some research / paper regarding this question, on how to prove the conjecture, or provide an example of some $F_d(n\neq d+1)$, it would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the answer is no: in the plane take three points not on a line and a fourth point inside the triangle. No matter how many points you add, the initial four points do not form a convex 4-gon.
This generalizes to all dimensions.

Comment: thanks for your answer! It seemed so to me, but just to check. Simple and direct proof!